# array_filter not working for multi dimensional array

Tags: php

Here is the non-functional code. It does not return anything. Not quite sure what is wrong with the syntax I am using.

```
 function findNeedle($array, $needle) {
        return array_values(array_filter($array, function($arrayValue) use($needle) { return $arrayValue['lp_url'] == $needle; } ));
 }
 $myarray =
         0 =>
         array (
           'lp_url' => 'http://example.com/nx/?utm_source=aa&utm_medium=referral',
           'lp_term_id' => 1435949468,
           'aff_term_id' => 1445295565,
           'offer_term_id' => 1445295996,
             ),
         1 =>
         array (
            'lp_url' => 'http://example.org/nx/?utm_source=aa&utm_medium=referral',
            'lp_term_id' => 1435949468,
            'aff_term_id' => 1445295559,
            'offer_term_id' => 1445295989,
            ),
         );

$needle = 'http://example.com/nx/?utm_source=aa&utm_medium=referral';
if (is_array($myarray)) {
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        $x = findNeedle($value, $needle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe describe what you want.  Since the code is non-functional it doesn't tell us much.

Comment: If the code returns true if the match is found and a false if match is not found (in lp_domain key), it would work for me.

Comment: `in_array($needle, array_column($myarray, 'lp_url'));` returns `true` or `false` if matched or not.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Also this works: `if(array_search($needle, array_column($myarray, 'lp_url')) !== False) {
    echo "FOUND";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
}`

Comment: Yes, that's a good one, but `array_search` returns a key so you have to compare with `false` as you have done.  `in_array` returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract an array of the data for the `lp_url` column and check for `$needle`:

```
if(in_array($needle, array_column($myarray, 'lp_url'))) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```